# Google Maps Search Box disappears after going to searched location

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using a cut-down version of Google Maps with a search box. The first time through the search box displays and allows you to go to the selected location. When at the selected location the search box does not display.

Can anybody enlighten me as to why the search box does not display at the new location.

The javascript link used is:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>
    <script>
```

The body code is:

```
<body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
    <input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Search Box">
</body>
```

The javascript code is:

```
<script>
    var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(-33.86428652, 151.20809555);
    var zoom = 14;

    function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
            center:     latLng,
            zoom:       zoom,
            mapTypeId:  google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

        var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
        map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);

        var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input); 

        google.maps.event.addListener(searchBox, 'places_changed', function() {
            var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

            if (places.length == 0)
                return;

            for (var i = 0; place = places[i]; i++) {
                latLng = place.geometry.location;   
            }

            initialize();
        });
    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that the `initialize` method is getting called after the input in the search box changes. This repeats the entire process of map initialization and places the search box everytime the input is changed. It is better to refactor this code having two functions

1. Initialize
2. Update Map

I have created a function as

```
function updateMap(){  
   map.setCenter(latLng);
}
```

And instead of giving call to `initialize` from places_changed listener, I have given call to `updateMap`

```
updateMap();
//initialize();
```

You can check the fiddle here
https://jsfiddle.net/a9Lo7kr7/

Comment: Thank you for the solution - it does work. The setCenter function provides an elegant simplicity to the solution, though it still does not explain why when calling initialize() a second time the search box is not displayed. Food for thought.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use my sample,
[image]

It's good solution for finding the location

You just need to change **key workd** or **Drag drop the map** for action

```js
var map;
      var service;
 
   var err = 0;
   var first = true;
   function initMap() {

   var lat = document.getElementById('start_lat').value;
  var lng = document.getElementById('start_lng').value;
  if(lat!='' && lng!='') {
   lat = parseFloat(lat);
   lng= parseFloat(lng);
    var center =   {lat: lat, lng:lng};   
    if(first){
     map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: center,
       zoom: 14
     });
      infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
     service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
     map.addListener('idle', performSearch);
     
   }
   else
   {
    map.setCenter(center);
    performSearch();
   }
   
  }
      }


      function performSearch() {

  var key = document.getElementById('keyword').value;
     var lat = document.getElementById('start_lat').value;
var lng = document.getElementById('start_lng').value;
  if(key!='' && lat!='' && lng!='')
  {
  var request = {
          bounds: map.getBounds(),
    type:[key],
    keyword: key
        };
        service.radarSearch(request, callback);
 }

      }
var arr_place =[];
var arr_pos = [];
function addRow(name, lat, lng, addr)
{
return;
 document.getElementById('con').innerHTML += ('"'+name+','+lat+','+lng+'",<BR>');
}

      function callback(results, status) {
        if (status !== google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
        //  console.error(status);
  //  setTimeout(changeCenter,500);
    return;
        }
  
  for (var i = 0, result; result = results[i]; i++) {
          
    if(arr_place.indexOf(result.place_id)==-1)
    {
   arr_place.push(result.place_id);
   addMarker(result);
   addRow( result.place_id, result.geometry.location.lat().toFixed(7), result.geometry.location.lng().toFixed(7), '');
   
  }
  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML=arr_place.length;
        }

      }
   var k=0;
 var cur =0;

 function ClearToResearch()
 {
  cnt = 0;
  arr_pos = [];
  for(var i=0; i<arr_mark.length; i++)
   arr_mark[i].setMap(null);
  arr_mark = [];
  var con = document.getElementById('con');
  while (con.firstChild) {
   con.removeChild(con.firstChild);
  }
  document.getElementById('keyword').value='';
  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML='0';
  
 }
 var arr_mark = [];
 var infoWindow;
      function addMarker(place) {
   var cur_pos = place.geometry.location;
   arr_pos.push(place);
   var marker;
        arr_mark.push( marker= new google.maps.Marker({
          map: map,
          position: cur_pos
        }));
  
  
   google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function() {
          service.getDetails(place, function(result, status) {
            if (status !== google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
              console.error(status);
              return;
            }
            infoWindow.setContent(result.name+'<BR>'+result.formatted_address);
            infoWindow.open(map, marker);
          });
        });
  
      }
```

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
        height: 450px;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
  padding-top:0px;
        padding-left:10px;
  padding-right:10px;
  background-color:rgb(215,215,215);
      }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Finding location</title>
  


  </head>
  <body>

<div id="container" style="white-space:nowrap">

    <div id="image" style="display:inline;">
    
    </div>

    <div id="texts" style="display:inline; white-space:nowrap;"> 
      <span style="vertical-align:middle;">  <font size=6 color=red><u><b>Finding location</b></u></font> </span>
    </div>

</div>​
 <form action="#" submit="performSearch()" >
 <font color=brown><b>Start Lat</b></font> <input type="text" id="start_lat" onchange="initMap()" value="25.164244">
 <font color=brown><b>Start Lng</b></font> <input type="text" id="start_lng" onchange="initMap()" value="55.287799">
 <font color=brown><b>Keyword</b></font> <input type="text" id="keyword" onchange="performSearch()" value="coffee">
 <font color=blue><b><span id="result"> 0 </span></b></font>
 <input type="button" value="Reset" onclick="ClearToResearch()" />
 <BR><BR>
    </form>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap&libraries=places,visualization" async defer></script>
 <div id="map" style="border:2px solid brown"></div>
 <BR>
 
 <div id="con">
  
 </table>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

As your are calling `google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);`

instead of

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&&libraries=places&callback=initialize"
    async defer></script>
```

As they are one and the same. Because `initialize()` that would be later invoked as callback function that is reason for search box to disappear every time after finding the location. 
I had solved this by

Attach a jQuery object instead of a DOM element inside a initialize() function

```
var pacinput = "<input id='pac-input' class='mapControlsq' type='text' placeholder='Enter a location'><br /><br />";
$('#map-canvas').append(pacinput);
var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);
```